# Red and white wine Mixed

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, grapes-wine, color

Is it a problem to mix red wine and white wine on Pesach because of the Problem of coloring on Yom Tov and is there a way to mix with out running into the problem of coloring?

Comment: This is a great question. I was wondering if coloring food on Yom Tov is any different than coloring food on Shabbos (in case that would be ossur on Shabbos, for example putting the color with the *intention* of making the food a different color.)

Comment: [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7036/537) explicitly mentions mixing red & white wine and permits it.

Comment: Rav Shalom Rosner’s Daf Yomi shiur for Chullin 129 discusses it and permits it around minute 38.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Halachafortoday sources the Mishna Brurah 320:56 :

> ‏(נו) מותר - וכן מותר ליתן יין אדום בתוך יין לבן ואע״פ שמתאדם [ואפילו אם מכוין לכתחלה לעשות מראה בהמאכל או בהמשקה ג״כ מסתברא דאין להחמיר כן נראה מהפמ״ג ולפי מה שכתב בנ״א נכון למנוע מזה] ומ״מ אין רשאי לעשות מראה ביי״ש ודבש שיקנו ממנו [פמ״ג ע״ש טעמו וגם בלא״ה הוא עובדא דחול] וכ״ש שלא להשים סממנים בצלוחית מים להעמיד בחלון נגד השמש ויש בזה חשש חיוב חטאת [שם בפמ״ג]׃

In short: To put red wine in white wine is not a problem; however, if the reason you are doing it is to make it red, then, although it seems that it is fine according to the Pri Megadim, it could be that it is better to stay away from such a thing (another reading).

The Shaarei Tziyon 318:65 writes it is better to put red in the cup and then add the white: this way everyone agrees it is permitted.

Comment: Is Yom Tov perhaps different than Shabbos in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt'l [allowed adding concentrated syrup to water or seltzer on shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1393/21), saying "this is no different than anyone who mixes water with wine or hot water with tea essence."

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Halachic Authority of any sort, but I believe there is no coloring of food.

If you want to be extra stringent, pour the red wine first. (i've seen Grand Rabbis do that).

Comment: Do you have any basis for your belief? Would you mind sharing it with us?

Comment: I happened to have thought that too I remember hearing Ain Tzoveh Bochel but I guess its wrong